# Selecionar os 3 meses anteriores

Tags: mysql

Olá, tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
----------------------
downloads | data
----------------------
10        | 2016-12-01
15        | 2016-12-02
20        | 2017-01-01
30        | 2017-02-01
40        | 2017-03-01
```

Dessa forma consigo somar o número de downloads do mês atual:

```
SELECT downloads, data,
SUM(downloads) AS soma
FROM tabela
WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Minha dúvida é, gostaria de selecionar o mês atual e os 3 anteriores:

```
12/2016: 25 Downloads
01/2017: 20 Downloads
02/2017: 30 Downloads
03/2017: 40 Downloads
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `GROUP BY` para agrupar por `MONTH()` e `YEAR()` e também utilizar o `WHERE` para apenas obter o que for maior que os últimos três meses.

```
SELECT   downloads, 
         data, 
         SUM(downloads) AS soma
FROM     tabela 
GROUP BY YEAR(data), 
         MONTH(data) DESC 
WHERE    data >= ( DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') )
```

Isso irá fazer com que agrupe por `YEAR(data), MONTH(data) DESC` e devido ao `WHERE` apenas irá aplicar para as datas que forem maiores do que o primeiro dia de três meses atrás.

---

- `YEAR(data), MONTH(data) DESC` agrupa tudo que for do mesmo ano e do mesmo mês. A sua *query* tem um problema em `MONTH(data) = MONTH(NOW())`, porque não considera que tanto `2016-12-01` quanto `2017-12-01` tem o mesmo mês (`12`), porém diferentes anos.
- `NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH` obtêm a data atual e *volta*  três meses, logo agora (`2017-03-03 16:54:53`) passa a ser `2016-12-03 16:54:53`.
- `DATE_FORMAT(..., '%Y-%m-01')` faz com que o `2016-12-03 16:54:53` passe a ser `2016-12-01`, ou seja sempre será o primeiro dia do mês.

> Se estiver usando `DATETIME`, mude para `%Y-%m-01 00:00:00`!

Comment: Perfeito Inkeliz, era isto que eu estava precisando. Obrigado :)